# Font-awesome with RefineryCMS

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, font-awesome, refinerycms

Could I use font-awesome with RefineryCMS?
When I added it via Bower and configure it in application.css like this:

```
*=require fontawesome
```

I got this error:

```
couldn't find file 'fontawesome'
```

at this line of code:

```
<%= csrf_meta_tags if Refinery::Core.authenticity_token_on_frontend -%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be

```
*=require font-awesome
```

and try to follow this link to force RefineryCMS use `<i>` instead of `<em>` 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/refinery-cms/TzzvxAAwmA0